# What is the meaning of "put in" in a conversation

Tags: conversation

I have visited Great Britain a while ago, and I communicate often with people from nordic countries, and from all of them I often hear the "put in" when someone don't understand or don't hear something that the other participant in the same verbal conversation is talking about. What is the meaning of this? it is correct to use this?

Comment: Can you write the full sentence? Did you just hear "Put in"?

Comment: I for one have no idea what you are talking about, Denees, Sorry.

Comment: And I'm equally mystified as to what this refers to.

Comment: Maybe it sounds different, but this is what I am hearing. It may be as well "Put em" or something like that. Let's say I am talking with someone and there are  misunderstandings in the conversations, so the other participant will ask this, so I will have to repeat one more time what I said.

Comment: Must have mispronounced or misheard the word *Pardon*.

Comment: It is from French, not sure that this was the word.

Comment: @Denees when you say 'there are misunderstandings' do you mean someone takes the wrong meaning, or that they cannot make out the meaning at all and are using this 'put in' phrase to ask for something to be repeated?

Comment: That's true, you're right

Comment: Like always there are people who cannot live without down voting someone's question/post, without trying to explaing/asking, what an unction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a native bilingual of both Swedish and English, and with the support of the dictionary, i can confidently state that the use of 'put in' as a way to communicate misunderstanding is indeed incorrect. As to the Swedish language the corresponding phrasal verb also lacks this meaning and it is thus unlikely that they would use it to convey such a sense of meaning too.

The closest you come to the use described in your post is is in: 
put in (one's) two cents['s worth]:
To share one's opinion or point of view for whatever it may be worth, generally when it is unasked for. E.g.: "I find Jeff's husband a bit trying at times. He always insists on putting in his two cents whether we want his opinion or not! If I can just put in my two cents, I think the staff would really appreciate a bump in their pay."

To conclude, it is incorrect to use the phrasal verb 'put in" to communicate misunderstandings. And Scandinavian speakers would also probably find it incorrect to do so. Hope this helped!

Dictionary used:
The Free Dictionary by Farlex

Comment: You mentioned a dictionary. Please add those references.